# instantiate a class from plugin in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, class, plugins

I have a question about class written in the plugin.  Let's say I have this class.

```
class Woo {

public static init(){
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( __CLASS__, 'woo_activate' ));

add_action( 'admin_menu', array(__CLASS__, 'woo_register'));
}

Woo::init();

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'Woo', 'init' ) );
```

My question is why put `Woo::init();` there where we already have the `add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'Woo', 'init' ) );`

Are both executed? can `woo::init()` be deleted and it will work fine? and vice versa?

Comment: I am curious where is this code from? It doesn't match the current version of WooCommerce.

Comment: This is my plugin.  I come up with it.  It work but I wonder why it works.

Comment: init() will be executed twice first by Woo::init() then by the action 'plugins_loaded'. The execution environment may have changed in such a way that the second init() may behave differently from the first. Without seeing what you have in init() I cannot say for certain but I think you only need one.

Comment: What line of codes do you think it's not current version of WooCommerce? I only use a class with a few action hook.

Comment: WooCommerce does not do its initialization in this way.